# Close MySQL Connection in Zend Framework (Or "Too many connections" solution)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, fgetcsv

After hours of trying and searching, I am hoping someone can help with my issue.

I created a CSV upload which works great on small numbers(at least 100 works fine).  When testing a file with 2,000 records or so, I get an error of "Connect Error: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections".

From what I can tell, this error can be resolved by closing my DB connection after insert, which I can not figure out how to do in Zend 2, all the results are for Zend 1.

If there is a better way to insert large records into MySQL from CSV, then I am open to those suggestions as well.

My controller code:

```
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ",")){
    $record = array_combine($header, $line);
    $record['group_id'] = $extra1;
    $employee->exchangeArray($record);
    $this->getEmployeeTable()->saveEmployee($employee);
}
```

And my saveEmployee code is just a basic Insert:

```
$adapter = new Adapter($dbAdapterConfig);
$sql = "INSERT INTO......;
$resultSet = $adapter->query($sql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

I believe adding a closeconnection() or something after $resultSet would resolve my issue.

Comment: you're probably creating a NEW connection for ever iteration of your loop, and eventually you exceed mysql's connection limit. The proper fix would be to remove the repetitive connection calls. there are very few usage cases that would ever require new/independent connections to the DB, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: why are you using more than 1 connection for the whole csv import?

Answer (score 0):

On every iteration you call your `saveEmployee` method so on every iteration you make a new instance of `Adapter`.

Move your `Adapter` initialization out of the while loop (before the loop) and you should be fine.